# limit_conn_zone Nginx Unknow error

Tags: nginx, limit, directive, connection, zone

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    http {
             limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:63m;

            server {
                 location /downloads/ {
                  limit_conn one 10;}

[root@batman1 ~]# service nginx configtest
nginx: [emerg] the size 66060288 of shared memory zone "one" conflicts with already declared size 0 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx!

I resolve my miss configuration.

Only changing of position my include to the final.

On nginx.conf I put the directive limit_conn_zone after the include.

and that cause the error.

Moving the include directive is all solve.